# Android 12: can't create new folder in downloads when app is uploaded to Google Play

Tags: android, android-12

When code bellow as a part of application is executed locally (directly started from Android Studio) it works correct.

```
String folderName = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(folderName) + "/SampleApp/");

if (!folder.mkdirs()) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new Exception("Storage access class: can't create folder");
    Log.d("Debug", "Can't create new folder on path: " + folder.getPath());
    return false;
}

return folder.exists();
```

The full path where new folder gets created is:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/SampleApp
```

But when the same code as a part of application gets uploaded to Google Play and then installed to the same phone, folder can't create and an exception gets triggered. Logged debug path is the same:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/SampleApp
```

I get the problem only on Android 12 devices. Has something specific changed from Android 11 to 12? I also tried using `mkdir()` but end result is the same. Inbetweeen both tests I obviously removed the SampleApp folder, so it doesn't exist when I try app version from Google Play.

Comment: Maybe you are forgetting to give the appropriate app permissions after you've installed it from Google Play?

Comment: Permission used are the same in both examples. If there weren't correct permission set, local version also wouldn't work.

Comment: No, I mean, as part of installing from the Android Studio you approved the needed permissions and when you installed from Google Play you simply forgot to approve those permissions, I'm asking if there's such a possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trying I found out that:

```
Files.createDirectory()
```

From: `java.nio.file` did the trick; instead of using `mkdir()`.